# VueJS default value for select not working

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I am tying to set a default value for a select in Vue.

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>

<div id="app">
  <select v:model="select">
       <option value="1">1</option>
       <option value="2">2</option>
       <option value="3">3</option>
  </select>
</div>

<script>
    new Vue({
      el: '#app',
      data: {
        select: '2'
      }
    })
<script>
```

I would expect the default value to be `2`, but it is `1` ?

Here is a fiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/dqgsbw9o/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is correct except for `v:model`. That should be `v-model`:

```
<select v-model="select">
```

[updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gdkhp9fv/)